# Parse a Prolog program with a Prolog program

Tags: parsing, prolog

I wanted to idly code a little Prolog preprocessor (sometimes in the futrue) ... and use Prolog directly to do that.

As I don't want to start [reinventing square wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel#Related_phrases) immediately, does the Prolog community know of a ready grammar (DCG program?) to hoover up tokens or text at one end and spit out terms at the other?

Comment: Why is it that term rewriting can not be used? I not saying your question is wrong but it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm not sure. Maybe it can!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use term expansion (see [SWI Prolog: Conditional compilation and program transformation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=progtransform)).
If you like to parsing Prolog, consider the paper:

[Prolog Coding Guidelines: Status and Tool Support](http://eptcs.web.cse.unsw.edu.au/paper.cgi?ICLP2019.8.pdf) by Nogatz et al presented on the [International Conference on Logic Programming 2019](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/ALP/iclp2019/index.html)

There is an implementation:
https://github.com/fnogatz/plammar

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out.